# How to view own Candidate Score for Moderator Election Nomination

Tags: discussion, election

As nomination phase is up for Community Moderator Election 2017, users have started nominating themselves as candidate for Moderator Election. Users are highlighting their background and expertise in SharePoint and their till date SharePoint StackExchange Comunity journey experiences.

For each nomination, a `Candidate Score` can be seen which gives overall idea about their profile strength.

So my question is, how one can view his `Candidate Score` prior to nomination, as this can be very helpful for the users before nomination otherwise I can see some of the users have nominated just to see their scores :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The Candidate Score can range from 0 to 40, and is calculated as
>   follows:
>
> - 1 point for each 1000 reputation up to 20,000 reputation for a maximum of 20 points.
> - 1 point each for Moderation badges - [Civic Duty](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty), [Cleanup](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup), [Deputy](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/140/deputy), [Electorate](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate), [Marshal](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal), [Reviewer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/169/reviewer),
>     [Sportsmanship](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/sportsmanship), [Steward](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward) - for a maximum of 8 points.
> - 1 point each for Editing badges - [Copy Editor](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor), [Explainer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer), [Organizer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/5/organizer), [Refiner](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/247/refiner), [Strunk and White](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), [Tag
>     Editor](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/tag-editor) - for a maximum of 6 points.
> - 1 point each for Participation badges - [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent), [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention), [Enthusiast](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/enthusiast), [Investor](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/investor), [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum),
>     [Yearling](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) - for a maximum of 6 points.
>
> For badges that can be awarded multiple times only 1 point is granted
>   for each badge type, thus ensuring a maximum score of 40 points.
>
> Stats are calculated based on the current state of the candidate, so
>   scores on past elections will *not* reflect the state of the
>   candidates at the time the election was run.

Accepted answer to [What are the details on the “candidate score” which shows during an election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252643/180230) on main meta site.

Answer (score 8):

Your candidate score would be 2, according to this [Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/sharepoint/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=186134). (The Data it is based on is from last Monday, so the score in principle could be higher now.) The source of the query is [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253783).

Generally, I think the decision to run should be based on your own understanding of the site and your possible contributions to it as a moderator, more than on any statistics.

That said, some may consider a candidate with single-digit candidate score a long shot, for their perceived lack of  activity on the site.

Comment: I'd say, as soon as you vote in the election (if you've never voted before), it will affect getting your [Constituent](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badge, which means one more point in your coffer. On Mechanics.SE I was sitting at 39/40 until I voted. Kind of surprised me, but it still applied and showed up during the election.